# Assign awk multiple variables

Tags: bash, awk

I'm using this command to check all sshd processes and CPU USAGE and CMD for sshd deamon:

```
ps -C sshd -o %cpu,cmd
```

example of output:

```
%CPU CMD
 0.0 sshd: root [priv]
 0.0 sshd: aadmin@pts/1
```

After that i've used:

```
ps -C sshd -o %cpu,cmd | awk '!/%CPU/ {print $1, $3}'
```

Output:

```
0.0 root
0.0 aadmin@pts/1
```

To sort CPU USAGE and third line, what i want is to assign `awk` output var to have output like this for multiple processes and in separate lines.

```
CPU_USAGE=0.0 USER=root
CPU_USAGE=0.0 USER=aadmin@pts/1
```

I've tried to assign variable to awk with `awk -v` but without success

Comment: Is the question how to get your output to look like that?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here but couldn't you just change your `print` to `print "CPU_USAGE="$1, "USER="$3`?

Comment: @EtanReisner yes, like this CPU_USAGE=0.0 USER=root
CPU_USAGE=0.0 USER=aadmin@pts/1

Comment: It's not clear what any of this has to do with variables. Can you update your question to explain what you mean?

Comment: It's also not clear what any of it has to do with `To sort CPU USAGE and third line`. Sort what? What third line?

Answer (score 3):

```
ps -C sshd -o %cpu,cmd | awk '!/%CPU/ {printf("CPU_USAGE=%s USER=%s\n", $1, $3)}'
```

You just have to format your `print` statement, for that, use `printf`.

Or shorter:

```
ps -C sshd -o %cpu,cmd | awk '!/%CPU/ {print "CPU_USAGE="$1, "USER="$3}'
```

Hope this is what u want. Your question was not clear otherwise...